# Emacs - how to determine if the control key is down

Tags: emacs, key, controls

I want an Emacs Lisp function to have two different behaviors depending on whether the control key is pressed or not.

Is there a way to query the state of the control key?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no facility to check the current state of a modifier key, but you can check whether the last key used to run the command was used with "control" or not:

```
(memq 'control (event-modifiers last-command-event))
```

Note that TAB and RET are actually the same as C-i and C-m, so they are considered as having a "control" modifier.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  Unfortunately, the last-command-event is a selection from a menu, and that does not seem to include the state of the modifier keys.  The action function of the selected menu-item is the code that I want to have modifiable behavior.

Comment: The "Emacs way" would be to let C-u (or any other universal argument) modify the behavior. You can pick this up using either `interactive` or `current-prefix-argument`.